# Html code does not adapt to tablet and cell phone

Tags: html, css, mediadevices

Im a complete Beginner and use Codes which i copy pasted from Codepen and put them together. It works but in Tablet or Handphone view it will not fit anymore, i tried Media Query but it doesn´t works or i make mistakes. So please someone can repair my Code that i can use it for my Website.

Thank you very much in advanced.

```css
*  {
    padding: 0;
    margin:  0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
.container {
    max-width: 500px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0 4%;
   padding-top: 65px;
   margin:0 auto;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}


.card {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
img {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 290px;
    bottom: -100px;
}

.shape {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -150px;
    bottom: 50px;
}

.text-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 40px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.text-container h2 {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.text-container p {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #d5d5d5;
    font-family: "bergen mono";
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}
a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
}

a > .fab {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src= "https://mathias-mastert-podcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/simon-lee-XnGxTBij48Q-unsplash.png">
        <img class="shape" src="https://mathias-mastert-podcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/simon-lee-ozVwowRmSwM-unsplash.png" alt="">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="text-container">
                <h2>STORE</h2>
                <p>Hier erhälst du das Wissen und die Fähigkeiten, die du brauchen, um im Podcast Universum erfolgreich zu sein.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use F12 on Chrome, then watch when the div are not adapted and take the width

then on css use

```
// -for exemple-
@media screen and (max-width: 1167px) {
   .container
   {
          max-width : 235px;
   }

}
```

Comment: Sorry does not work or i do it wrong.

Comment: What did you put in media screen ?

Comment: Different Codes. The Picture, the Container itself, the Card.

What i need is a Fixed Code because my Code is a Frankenstein, i made it out of Codepen Codes mixed with my own Pictures. Im a totally beginner and have no knowledge how to do this right and how it can look well on all devices.